# Weight distribution roof construction

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering

How do I calculate the maximum force on a support beam if I know the weight of the roof? 
I assume distribution will be even but I cannot find correct formulas.

For example: 3 beams 60cm apart supporting a roof of 70kg/m2

Answer (score 1):

For a roof it'd be normal to assume even distribution of load.

Don't forget to include applied load (e.g. snow) as well as the dead weight. And don't forget to include any safety factors required in your jurisdiction.